# Two different interpretation for the given sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this sentence:

> Before they begin the project, the study must be done of its feasibility.

Which, in my book, might be used for two different occasions either *suggestion* or *regular routine*.
For more clarity:

**Suggestion** - Suppose a situation in which the project has been concluded with an unsatisfactory result and an expert utters, as a useful consideration: "Before ... feasibility"

**Regular Routine** - Now suppose during a process of a project, an engineer tells another about the criteria that the whole group is adhered to, and he states: "Before ... feasibility"

Are these both interpretations are correct about this sentence or I have not noticed something?
And if so, what are the correct possible sentences for two instances mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one interpretation of the statement.

**A study of the project's feasibility must be done before the project commences.** (..before they begin it).

The project clearly hasn't yet started or been concluded. Otherwise, the statement would have to read: **Before they began the project, a study should have been done of its feasibility.**